# Pass null value to controller

Tags: javascript

I have a variable which I want to pass to controller, it's a date format which I want to send it as seconds,

```
var f = $("#from").val(); var from_mili = Date.parse(f);
```

Here is my AJAX request:

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: "json",
    type: "POST",
    url: "@Url.Action("EventEntries", "Turbine")",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: JSON.stringify({"from": (from_mili / 1000) }),
    success: function (result) {
        debugger;
    }
});
```

The problem is when I divide it by 1000 to get seconds out of it in controller I get null but when I send without the division I get the value.

```
 public JsonResult EventEntries(long? from = null)
```

Comment: You are dividing a `Date` object with a `number`. The result can't be a number....

Comment: What's the actual POST body (in the dev tools)?

Comment: @ADreNaLiNe-DJ what should I do?

Comment: Can you show console.log from JSON.Stringyfy line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To complete the @phuzi answer, there's another mistake in your code.

The first is the division of a `Date` with a `number`. @phuzi's answer gives a solution for this issue.

The second issue is that you use `stringify` in you ajax call which is useless because of your `contentType`set to `json`.

So your code should look like this:

```
var f = $("#from").val();
var from_mili = Date.parse(f);
var from = Math.floor(from_mili / 1000);
var data = { from: from };
$.ajax({
    dataType: "json",
    type: "POST",
    url: "@Url.Action("EventEntries", "Turbine")",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: data,
    success: function (result) {
        debugger;
    }
});
```

Then, the default value for your `from`argument in `C#` is useless: you're using a `nullable` type. It does not solve an issue but it's an advice about something which is useless.

```
public JsonResult EventEntries(long? from)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `from_mili` appears to be getting set incorrectly: `f` is being set to a string which comes out as `NaN` when passed to `Date.parse()` which then breaks when divided by `1000`.

Try this instead:

```
var f = $('#from').val();
var from_mili = Date.parse (parseInt (f));

$.ajax({
    dataType: "json",
    type: "POST",
    url: "@Url.Action("EventEntries", "Turbine")",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: JSON.stringify({"from": (from_mili / 1000) }),
    success: function (result) {
        debugger;
    }
});
```

Comment: It does not change the problem: you cannot divide a `Date` object (`from_mili` type) with a `number` (`1000`).

Comment: @ADreNaLiNe-DJ so how do get seconds out of a date?

Comment: @mrsol83 `valueOf` function of a `Date` object returns the value of the date in `milliseconds` since January 1st 1970. So, you can divide this value by `1000` to obtain the number of `seconds` you need. You should look closely to phuzi's answer and comments.

Comment: @ADreNaLiNe-DJ I did that and I get the proper value by dividing the value by 1000,but the thing is still in the controller I get "null",i don't know what the hell is the difference when I remove the division I get the value in controller as soon as in divide by 1000 or any thing ,I get null

Comment: @mrsol83 Take a look to the answer I posted.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to divide a Date object by a number!

Change

```
var from_mili = Date.parse(f);
```

to

```
var from_mili = Date.parse(f).valueOf();
```

Comment: I still get Null in controller,when I divide by 1000,

Comment: @mrsol83 Hmm, having divided by 1000 you've now got a floating point number... Could be that the ValueResolver is not liking a floating point number. Try `Math.floor(from_mili / 1000)`